# uncheck a radio button - laravel

Tags: laravel, radio-button, laravelcollective

I have multiple radio button options to filter out results.
I also have a CLEAR button, which is supposed to reload the page with all products (un-filtered).
The button works correctly in the sense that it unfilters all the products, however the radio buttons still remain checked.

This is how I am defining the radio button initially:

```
{{ Form::radio('property', 'Full') }} {{ Form::label('a', 'Full') }}
```

The clear button redirects the page to another view where the button is defined as follows:

```
    {{ Form::radio('property', 'Full', false) }} {{ Form::label('a', 'Full') }}
```

However the button remains checked still.

Is there a way to reset them?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the false and it should be the default which is unchecked

Comment: could you show more code like the context in which those radio buttons are defined, maybe you have some conditional somewhere?